# How to make the two positional values in a python function be entered in one input

Tags: python, intellij-idea

```
def banner_text(text,screen_width):

    if len(text) > screen_width -4:
        print("EEK!!!")
        print("THE TEXT IS TOO LONG TO FIT IN THE SPECIFIED WIDTH ")

    if text == "*":
        print("*" * screen_width)
    else:
        centred_text =text.center(screen_width - 4)
        output_string = "**{0}**".format(centred_text)
        print(output_string)


print("Banner text app ,is used to make normal text into banner text\n"
      "asterisk '*' makes a line of *\n"
      "& space makes line of spaces\n"
      "Enter banner width after text to get specific width \n")


print()
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
banner_text(input())
```

I tried to use an input command then a comma & another input command in the function. I expected it to consider the second input as the second parameter but the code crashed.

Comment: You need to learn how to use loops; you should never have to have the same line repeated multiple times like that. Also, the way you can break up the inputted string is with [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).

Comment: You need to do `*input().split(','`)`

Comment: `banner_text(*input().split(","))` note however that these will be strings and your method will need to cast the second parameter to an int.

Answer (score 0):

You have two alternatives.

1. Use a single input where the user specifies two values using a comma e.g. "Hello World, 20". The input then needs to be split along the comma using `split(',')`. This `split()` turns the single input into a list of two arguments which we iterate by using the `*` operator. This is the answer you're seeing in the comments.
2. If you are always going to use `input()` as the arguments to your function, just place two `input()` in your function and remove the arguments.

Keep in mind that with both options, whatever the user inputs is read as a `string`, so you have to cast the second argument as an `int`.

Option 1:

```
def banner_text(text,screen_width):
    screen_width = int(screen_width)
    if len(text) > screen_width -4:
        print("EEK!!!")
        print("THE TEXT IS TOO LONG TO FIT IN THE SPECIFIED WIDTH ")

    if text == "*":
        print("*" * screen_width)
    else:
        centred_text =text.center(screen_width - 4)
        output_string = "**{0}**".format(centred_text)
        print(output_string)

banner_text(*input().split(','))
```

Option 2:

```
def banner_text():
    text = input()
    screen_width = int(input())
    if len(text) > screen_width -4:
        print("EEK!!!")
        print("THE TEXT IS TOO LONG TO FIT IN THE SPECIFIED WIDTH ")

    if text == "*":
        print("*" * screen_width)
    else:
        centred_text =text.center(screen_width - 4)
        output_string = "**{0}**".format(centred_text)
        print(output_string)

banner_text()
```